# TaskCanceled Exception while creating relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm creating Relationship between existing nodes.
I have around 200k nodes in my graph. 
while creating relationship through neo4jClient i get **TaskCanceled(i.e. Timeout Exception)**

```
MATCH (user:User)
MATCH (friend:User)
WHERE friend.ThirdPartyFriendId IN user.ThirdPartyFriendsIds
CREATE UNIQUE user-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->friend
```

Comment: Usually TaskCancelled means you're querying via HTTP.  Increase the HTTP timeout in your client (whatever that is) to help avoid this.   What does "2 lakh nodes" mean?   Also, the way you've formulated your query is going to take a lot of time, it's very inefficient.  This is practically producing a cartesian product of all User nodes in your database, since you're matching all User's twice.   You're checking to see if a friend ID is in some set -- but this is usually the sort of operation you would have wanted to model with relationships, not properties.

Comment: I think lakh means 100,000 so 2 lakh is 200,000 (only a quick google)

Comment: @FrobberOfBits is correct. You might be timing out because your query is O(N*N), and therefore taking too long to complete. You should have created your nodes and the FRIENDS_WITH relationships at the outset, instead of first storing the relationship information in node properties.

Comment: Yikes!    200,000 nodes is no big deal, but 200,000 ^2 = 40 billion could be a problem...this query needs to be formulated some other way!

Comment: Perhaps it should be executed for a concrete user? Another option is to index `ThirdPartyFriendId`. Perhaps it even makes sense to create nodes and relationships for those "third-party-friends" and then just create the short-cut-relationship.